# How to export the object in PDF format in addition to Excel format?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a Java Script code that currently exports objects in Excel format, I want to upgrade this code so that it also exports objects in PDF format

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Qlik Sense Mashup</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://pa-qliksense.aviv.gov.il/sense/app/7066663c-68b7-4587-ab36-762ab1cdd580"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <script src="../../resources/assets/external/requirejs/require.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="overflow: auto">
    <div id="CurrentSelections" class="qvobjects" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:38px;"></div>
    <!-- Qlik Sense object placeholder -->
    <div id="QFgJHd"></div>

    <!-- Placeholder for displaying the download link -->
    <div id="downloadLink" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>

    <!-- Automatically trigger export on page load -->
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            // Get parameters from URL
            var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            var fieldName1 = urlParams.get('fieldName1');
            var fieldValue1 = urlParams.get('fieldValue1');
            var fieldName2 = urlParams.get('fieldName2');
            var fieldValue2 = urlParams.get('fieldValue2');


            // Call exportData function with parameters
            exportData(fieldName1, fieldValue1, fieldName2, fieldValue2);
        };

        function exportData(fieldName1, fieldValue1, fieldName2, fieldValue2) {
            var prefix = window.location.pathname.substr(0, window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("/extensions") + 1);
            var config = {
                host: window.location.hostname,
                prefix: prefix,
                port: window.location.port,
                isSecure: window.location.protocol === "https:"
            };

            require.config({
                baseUrl: (config.isSecure ? "https://" : "http://") + config.host + (config.port ? ":" + config.port : "") + config.prefix + "resources"
            });

            require(["js/qlik"], function(qlik) {
                qlik.setOnError(function(error) {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
                });

                // Open app
                var app = qlik.openApp('7066663c-68b7-4587-ab36-762ab1cdd580', config);

                // Set specific field values as selections
                app.field(fieldName1).selectValues([fieldValue1], true, false);
                app.field(fieldName2).selectValues([fieldValue2], true, false);

                // Get table object
                app.getObject('QFgJHd').then(function(model) {
                    // Create a table object
                    var table = qlik.table(model);

                    // Export data from the table
                    table.exportData({ download: true, format: 'OOXML' }).then(exportData => {
                        // Display the download link
                        var downloadLinkElement = document.getElementById('downloadLink');
                        downloadLinkElement.innerHTML = '<a href="' + exportData + '" download="exported_data.xlsx">Download Data</a>';
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error exporting table data:', error);
                        alert('Error exporting table data. See console for details.');
                    });
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error getting table object:', error);
                    alert('Error getting table object. See console for details.');
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want you to give ideas how to export in PDF format, I tried to do it like I did in Excel format with PDF extension but it fails to export it properly..........................................................

Comment: At the moment it downloads the file for me as an Excel file, are you saying that it is not possible to download the file as a PDF file as well?

Comment: I would like to hear more ideas for exporting in PDF format

Answer (score 0):

You were already able to retrieve the data from Qlik.Table and handle it to export as Excel. Have you considered using jsPDF to generate the data above to PDF?
I have prepared a quick demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/sontran1206/26yagjhu/

```
function generatePDF(){
  var doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.setFontSize(14);
  let table = document.querySelector("#simpleTable1");
  doc.fromHTML(table, 20, 20);
  doc.save('my.pdf');
}

let buttonPdf = document.querySelector("#button-pdf");

buttonPdf.addEventListener("click", generatePDF);
```

Basically the code above retrieve data from HTML and export as PDF, this can be replaced by your Qlik.Table.

If you need to format the data on your PDF, you may modify the code above to adapt your output expectation.